# Is there a way to avoid login when using --privileged to run a docker container

Tags: docker, containers, centos7, docker-run, docker-privileged

I'm using a docker of image centos:7.9.2009, is there a way to avoid login when using `--privileged=true` to run a container?
Here is the command:

```
docker run -d --privileged=true -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup --name centos_base centos:7.9.2009 /usr/sbin/init
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcXYr.png)

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  In normal use you shouldn't need `--privileged` at all.  It looks like you might be trying to run the heavy-weight systemd init system as the main container process, but for normal use you should be able to ignore systemd and just run the thing you're packaging as a foreground process as the image's `CMD`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.